# How can I retain zero in python for calculation?

Tags: python

So I supposed to verify if the input number is a UPC number or not. I have to allowed leading zeros and accounted it in the calculation.

Here is my current code, it works for all number except number has leading zeros:

Condition for UPC code valid:

- Calculate the sum of multiplying odd digit index by 3 and even digit index by 1 of the input number.
- Calculate the sum we just did modulo 10, get result digit.
- If the resulting digit is between 1 and 9 then subtract result digit from 10. If the result digit is 0, add 0 to the to the base number to get the completed number.

```
def UPC_code(num):
    sum_digit = 0
    index = 0
    num_temp = str(num)[:-1]
    len_nt = len(num_temp)

    for digit in num_temp:                  
        if (index + 1) % 2 != 0:            # If number position is odd
            sum_digit += int(digit) * 3     # Sum = digit * 3
            if index < len_nt:              # Increase index till end
                index += 1
        elif (index + 1) % 2 == 0:          # If number position is even
            sum_digit += int(digit) * 1     # Sum = digit * 1
            if index < len_nt:
                index += 1
    # print(sum_digit)

    res_digit = sum_digit % 10
    if 1 <= res_digit <= 9:
        res_digit = 10 - res_digit      # Res digit meet condition = 10 - res digit

    if res_digit == num % 10:
        return True
    elif res_digit != num % 10:
        return False
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")
# End UPC_code()
```

Call UPC_code()

```
import code_check.py as cc

num = str(input())
num_int = int(num)
if cc.UPC_code(num_int) is True and num_int != 0:
    print(num, "valid UPC code.")
else:
    print("Not valid")
```

Expected input:

```
042100005264
```

Expected output:

```
042100005264 valid UPC code
```

Actual output:

```
Not valid
```

Comment: What are the conditions for a UPC code to be valid?

Comment: @not_speshal I have added it, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can greatly simplify your code with string slicing.  Assuming using `num` as a 12-digit string, `sum(int(x) for x in num[:-1:2])` will compute the sum of the odd digits and `sum(int(x) for x in num[1:-1:2])` will compute the sum of the even digits.  In the latter case, `1:-1:2` means "start at index 1 (2nd digit), up to but not including last digit, step by 2".  Then the check digit becomes `check = (10 - (odd * 3 + even) % 10) % 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it works for all number except number has leading zeros

As you have doubtless discovered, python does not allow you to write `0700`.  Historically that would have meant `0o700`, or 448, which is likely not what you want anyhow...

In this case the solution is simple.  If you need to handle numbers like `00007878979345`, handle strings.

Thus refactor your code to take a string.  As a bonus, `int("000008")` is `8`, so when you need the number as a number you don't even have to do anything.

Comment: Correct. All he has to do is change the input for his function to a string, and then he can go one char at a time, conduct the test, and output the string again if it passes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was searching around at the same time but it seems it impossible to make it works with pure interger.

Comment: indeed---because of the historical meaning of leading zeros (signifying octal)